# Changing value of a span every 1 second infinit times using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the value of a span after every one second infinite time but I'm not getting how to do this task. Right now I am using setTimeout function which change all values one time when values are finished it ends.

```
   <span id="second-span"></span>

   <script>
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("second-span").innerHTML = "Creator ";', 0);
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("second-span").innerHTML = "Foodie ";', 3000);
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("second-span").innerHTML = "Traveller";', 6000);
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("second-span").innerHTML = "Fitness Freak";', 9000);
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("second-span").innerHTML = "Makeup Genie";', 12000);
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("second-span").innerHTML = "Vlogger";', 15000);
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("second-span").innerHTML = "Filmmaker";', 18000);
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("second-span").innerHTML = "Artist  ";', 21000);
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("second-span").innerHTML = "Narrator";', 24000); 

</script>
```

Can you please tell me how I can do this task infinite times.I'm new to javascript so please guide me I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: You can use setInterval. But why you wanna do this ?

Comment: And what goes after "Narrator"? How do you pick next word "infinite times"? Repeating some list of values? :)

Comment: I want to keep repeating these 9 values but not getting idea how to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store all values in a list. And start a function that picks a value at some index, updates the index, and restarts itself in a second.

```js
const values = ['Creator', 'Foodie', 'etc']
let index = 0

const change = () => {
  document.getElementById('to-change').innerHTML = values[index];
  index = ++index % values.length;
  setTimeout(change, 1000);
}

change()
```

```html
<span id="to-change" />
```

Comment: Was going to post something similar to this. You beat me to it lol +1

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I was stuck at this problem for the past 3 hours once again thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setInterval`

```
function func() {
    // Do something here
}

setInterval(func,1000) // Runs func function every 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`.
But you have to know that both of these take two parameters, one is a callback function, not a string. The other parameter is the number of milliseconds at which the callback will be called. In case of `setInterval` the callback function will be triggered every n number of milliseconds as you specified in the second parameter.

You also need to shorten your code a little bit to make it readable. There is no need to repeat yourself quite often.

```
var span = document.getElementById("second-span");

setInterval(function(){ span.innerHTML = "Creator ";     }, 0);
setInterval(function(){ span.innerHTML = "Foodie ";      }, 3000);
setInterval(function(){ span.innerHTML = "Traveller";    }, 6000);
setInterval(function(){ span.innerHTML = "Fitness Freak";}, 9000);
setInterval(function(){ span.innerHTML = "Makeup Genie"; }, 12000);
setInterval(function(){ span.innerHTML = "Vlogger";      }, 15000);
setInterval(function(){ span.innerHTML = "Filmmaker";    }, 18000);
setInterval(function(){ span.innerHTML = "Artist  ";     }, 21000);
setInterval(function(){ span.innerHTML = "Narrator";     }, 24000);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but that one didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval, but it is also not recommended. Recommended is to use setTimeout recursively:

```
<span id="second-span"></span>

<script>
  function cycleArr (elm, arr, int) {
    const next = (idx => arr => idx = ++idx % arr.length)(-1)

    function* getItems (arr) {
      for (;;) yield arr[next(arr)]
    }

    +function cycle (out, items, int) {
      out.textContent = items.next().value
      setTimeout(cycle, int, out, items, int)
    }(elm, getItems(arr), int)
  }

  let arr = [
    'Creator',
    'Foodie',
    'Traveller',
    'Fitness Freak',
    'Makeup Genie',
    'Vlogger',
    'Filmmaker',
    'Artist',
    'Narrator'
  ]
  let int = 1 * 1000 // Every 1 sec.
  let elm = document.querySelector('#second-span')

  cycleArr(elm, arr, int)
</script>
```